# angular project .js file generation configuration option

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Please see this image. I see a constants.js file and "js.map" file under the constants.ts file. while I see no js file for other ts files. I understand that the type script compiler will generate the js file for each ts file. I am not sure why I can not see all the js files. I am not sure which configuration setting is affecting this. project is under source control. I only want to commit to the .ts files. I need to stop any ".js" or "js.map" files from being generated. not sure why it is only happening for one file. This is .Net core project with angular frontend.

[image]